# How to remove this error?

Tags: errors

here I have this error, but don't know how to remove it .
[image]

this is coding
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example as a compilable code snippet, not a screenshot here, because we have to copy + paste your code for testing.

Comment: please post code and error messages as text not as an image, but as the image shows, if you type `h` to that prompt, it will give more details, telling you the clashing options and suggesting how to change your document to avoid it.

Comment: `l.46` means line 46, not line 146

Comment: You're loading `caption` twice, with different options.